# What are these numbers in the code GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000 ? Are they essential?

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to find any logical explanation to these numbers and their meaning in the simple action of pressing a key.
`GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000;` .

What other values can be used instead of `0x8000` and what do they have to do with pressing a key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetAsyncKeyState according to the documentation returns

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down ...

If you take the number 0x8000 and write it out in binary it will be

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

That bit on the far left is called "the most significant bit"

What the the `&` operator does is it does a bitwise AND which means only bits that are a `1` in both sides of the `&` will be in the result.

Doing `& 0x8000` is a way to mask off (ignore) all of the bits except for the most significant bit. You can then check the result of this operation is `!= 0` and that will return true or false depending on if the key you passed in to the function was pressed down.

As your code is tagged c# but this function is from the native windows functions the example you may have seen this from may have just looked like

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) {
    ...
}
```

in C++ there is a implicit check of `!= 0` in the if statement so any non zero value is treated as true.

Comment: Where can one acquire this documentation ?

Comment: If you type in GetAsyncKeyState in to google the first result is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate